# Need help transferring ranges from one workbook to another with each range going to a separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, I need to copy `Ranges 1,2,3,4 and 5` from one `Workbook` to another. This ranges must be pasted in the next row of the data set in the `Sheets 1,2,3,4 and 5` of the target `Workbook`. This way I can continously add data.

I can't figure out how to use `LastRow`

This is what I have that works for `Activeworkbook.range1` to `filetoOpen` Sheet 1.
This just replaces the data each time I run the macro.

```
Sub Export_Data_To_File()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = "S:\Process Engineering\Team Documents\010 Alpha\Alpha Laser Calibration\Raw Data\Raycus 
Laser Decay Comparison.xlsx"
'lastRow = OpenBook.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

If FileToOpen <> False Then

    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("G6:L6").Copy
    OpenBook.Worksheets("100% Duty Cycle").Range("B3:G3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    OpenBook.Worksheets("100% Duty Cycle").Range("A3") = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")
    OpenBook.Save
    OpenBook.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do not `.Copy` and `.Paste()` but rather use the `.Value` property to directly write the values.

Comment: You want to copy from the last row of the current sheet, to the last row of the file to open? I noticed it is always 6 columns, is that true?

Comment: The ranges I want to copy are (G6:L6), (G12:L12), (G18,L18), (G24:L24), (G30:L30) all from the same sheet.  Each range then needs to be pasted in a different sheet in the last row of the file to open.  They will always be 6 columns.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add all this information in detail. Where is the data coming from and where does it go into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Remember to config the code before you run it.

```
Sub TransferData()

Dim main_workbook As Workbook, target_workbook As Workbook
Dim r1 As String, r2 As String, r3 As String, r4 As String, r5 As String
Dim s0 As String, s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String, s4 As String, s5 As String
Dim next_row As Long, col_number As Integer, close_workbook As Boolean

'CONFIG HERE
'------------------------------------
'workbook path to copy from
Set main_workbook = ThisWorkbook

'workbook path to paste in
Set target_workbook = _
Workbooks.Open("/Users/user/Desktop/Raycus  Laser Decay Comparison.xlsx")

'ranges r1,r2,r3,r4,r5 from main_workbook
'-------------------------------------
r1 = "G6:L6"
r2 = "G12:L12"
r3 = "G18:L18"
r4 = "G24:L24"
r5 = "G30:L30"
'-------------------------------------
s0 = "Sheet1"   'sheet name to copy from
'-------------------------------------
s1 = "Sheet1"    'sheet name to paste r1
s2 = "Sheet2"    'sheet name to paste r2
s3 = "Sheet3"    'sheet name to paste r3
s4 = "Sheet4"    'sheet name to paste r4
s5 = "Sheet5"    'sheet name to paste r5

col_number = 1 'column number to paste

close_workbook = True 'close the target_workbook once the macro ends?
'-----------------------------
'END OF CONFIG

'turn screen updating off
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'copy range1 from main_workbook & get the next row of s1 in the target workbook
main_workbook.Sheets(s0).Range(r1).Copy
next_row = target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Cells(Rows.Count, col_number).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'paste range1 in sheet s1 of the target_workbook
target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Cells(next_row, col_number).PasteSpecial

'copy range2 from main_workbook & get the next row of s2 in the target workbook
main_workbook.Sheets(s0).Range(r2).Copy
next_row = target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Cells(Rows.Count, col_number).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'paste range2 in sheet s2 of the target_workbook
target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Cells(next_row, col_number).PasteSpecial

'copy range3 from main_workbook & get the next row of s3 in the target workbook
main_workbook.Sheets(s0).Range(r3).Copy
next_row = target_workbook.Sheets(s3).Cells(Rows.Count, col_number).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'paste range3 in sheet s of the target_workbook
target_workbook.Sheets(s3).Cells(next_row, col_number).PasteSpecial

'copy range4 from main_workbook & get the next row of s4 in the target workbook
main_workbook.Sheets(s0).Range(r4).Copy
next_row = target_workbook.Sheets(s4).Cells(Rows.Count, col_number).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'paste range4 in sheet s4 of the target_workbook
target_workbook.Sheets(s4).Cells(next_row, col_number).PasteSpecial

'copy range5 from main_workbook & get the next row of s5 in the target workbook
main_workbook.Sheets(s0).Range(r5).Copy
next_row = target_workbook.Sheets(s5).Cells(Rows.Count, col_number).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'paste range5 in sheet s5 of the target_workbook
target_workbook.Sheets(s5).Cells(next_row, col_number).PasteSpecial

'save
target_workbook.Save

'turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'close target_workbook in the end?
If close_workbook Then
    target_workbook.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: a) Anytime you see that same code over and over, it is time to implement loops and arrays. b) Copy/Paste has issues, it is much faster and cleaner to write values to cells directly with the `.Value2` property.

Comment: I appreciate everything you have done.  I will try this out and let you know if it works.  Also I will use this in the future to learn from as well.

Comment: Thanks for the message. Yea, let me know if it works. If it doesn't we could try to make some adjustments to make it work.

Comment: You need something really different from what I coded. All fives sheets are in the same file "Raycus Laser Decay Comparison.xlsx" right?

Comment: Yes.  Each of the sheets that get pasted to are in the same "FileToOpen".  All the ranges are copied from the same sheet in the ActiveWorkBook.

Comment: Okay, I modified it. It should work now. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Since the workbook that I will be copying from will change every time cant I just use 
ThisWorkBook instead of Set main_workbook = _
Workbooks.Open("/Users/user/Desktop/main.xlsm")

Comment: This almost works perfectly.  I just have to figure out the #Ref error in the cells that were copied too and then add the date to column A when the marco is ran.

Comment: I don't understand the #Ref error you are talking about, but the date thing is easy, use `target_workbook.Sheets("sheetname").Cells(next_row, 1) = Date`. I think those final touches are yours to make. The code is very understandable. Good luck ;)

Comment: I got it all figured out.  The Ref error was in the new FileToOpen workbook because I was copying a formula over and not just the values.  I just had to change it to paste values instead of standard .paste.  I did figure out the date thing as well.  I am very thankful for the help.

Comment: nice to know you made it work! appreciate your comment. I did learn with this code, so it was useful for me as well. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested the code, but try the following:

Create arrays with the files and source ranges. Tnen call `Export_Data_To_File()` for each combination. All you need is the first cell, as you can use `.Resize(1,6)` to reference 6 columns and one row from the first cell. Also, the data is first copied into a memory array `vals` and then this array is used to write the data to the destination.

```
Sub Export_All_Data()

    Const projFolder As String = "S:\Process Engineering\Team Documents\"
    
    Dim filesToOpen As Variant
    Dim sourceRanges As Variant
    
    filesToOpen = Array( _
        projFolder & "010 Alpha\Alpha Laser Calibration\Raw Data\Raycus\Laser Decay Comparison.xlsx", _
        projFolder & "011 Alpha\Alpha Laser Calibration\Raw Data\Raycus\Laser Decay Comparison.xlsx", _
        projFolder & "012 Alpha\Alpha Laser Calibration\Raw Data\Raycus\Laser Decay Comparison.xlsx", _
        projFolder & "013 Alpha\Alpha Laser Calibration\Raw Data\Raycus\Laser Decay Comparison.xlsx", _
        projFolder & "014 Alpha\Alpha Laser Calibration\Raw Data\Raycus\Laser Decay Comparison.xlsx")
        
    sourceRanges = Array("G6", "G12", "G18", "G24", "G30")
    
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    n = 5
    For i = 1 To n
        Call Export_Data_To_File(filesToOpen(i - 1), sourceRanges(i - 1))
    Next i

End Sub

Sub Export_Data_To_File(ByVal fileToOpen As String, ByVal srcRange As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")

    Dim vals As Variant
    vals = ws.Range(srcRange).Resize(1, 6).Value2
    
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(fileToOpen)
    Set ws = OpenBook.Worksheets("100% Duty Cycle")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Cells(lastRow, 2).Resize(1, 6).Value2 = vals  ' 2nd column, lastrow
    ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")
    OpenBook.Save
    OpenBook.Close False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: After running this code all 6 ranges are copied to the same sheet in the openfile workbook.  Is there a way to use an array to have the first range paste to the first sheet in the openfile workbook and the 2nd range to the 2nd sheet and so on?